# The meaning of the phrasal verb "get on" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I have come across it in this [video](https://youtu.be/CDO_l4wX9Qs). It is at 6 minutes and 5 seconds.

> Still, there have been attempts to create circular and square smartphones, but as you can guess, they didn't **get on**.

Does the *get on* mean *catch on* in the sentence? I am a bit puzzled because I didn't find that definition of *get on* in dictionaries.

Comment: Probably meaning "get on board (yet)."

Comment: They mean: the attempts to do that didn't go forward. It's just one of  a lapsus.

Comment: I speak American English. "Get on" (in this context) is not an idiom we use. I think "catch on' is more idiomatically correct

Comment: I think I see what's going on after looking at the video. The diction is trying to be folksy. Phrases like " didn't get on" sound contrived and a little unnatural to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Get on" here means "get very far, proceed a significant way toward success." The authors may mean either technical or commercial success.